# Connect to a remote ActiveMQ broker

Tags: activemq-classic, remote-access

I am trying to make a connection from a Java application to a remote ActiveMQ broker.

The remote URL is read from a properties file specified as:

```
tcp://<remote URL>:1883
```

The remote ActiveMQ broker's activemq.xml has entries like below:

```
<transportConnectors>

            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

Both the Java application and the remote broker are running on Windows machine.

I am also able to access the admin URL of the remote broker in the browser but the connection through the Java application is failing.

Can someone please help ?

Regards

Comment: why are you specifying port as `1883` instead of `61616` in your connection URL,

correct way to do is `tcp://remote-ip:61616`

Comment: I am trying to create an MQTT connection and hence specifying the port as 1883.

Comment: ok... any exception?

Comment: It gives a connection exception: 'Timed out waiting for a response from the server (32000)'. The same thing works when I try to connect to the local store bus: tcp://localhost:1883

Comment: What client are you using?  Is there a firewall in between?  You need to provide enough information so that someone that is not sitting at your desk can try to help.

Comment: If this would have been a firewall issue, I would have already mentioned that.